# problem in installing mayavi package by pip in windows command prompt

Tags: python, pycharm, python-idle, mayavi

I am a beginner in python. I use windows 10 and IDLE. I have cloned a code from github and there are a bunch of *.py files. when I run the main code in python IDLE there is an error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mayavi'

I tried to install mayavi in windows cmd using "pip", but again there is a long error starting with this sentence:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

it seems that it is a bit complicated to install mayavi.
is this package installation thing a problem in IDLE? what if I use another IDE?
In fact I am not sure that IDLE is a good choice for coding python or not? In addition I am using python 3.10.1.

I look forward to hearing your advices.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `pip install mayavi PyQt5`

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/mayavi/

Comment: still a long error containing this message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtk'

Comment: `pip install vtk mayavi PyQt5`

Comment: This is a duplicate of perhaps 50 similar questions.  IDLE is not relevant except that you must install packages for the python you use to run IDLE.  Please search python issues for 'Module not found' and read some of the answers for more.  You should likely use `py -3.10 -m pip install mayavi ...` in Command Prompt

Comment: Try to downgrade python to 3.9 version, mayavi is not ready for the 3.10 yet

Answer (score 0):

Try [AnaConda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual). It will manage the installation of python packages in an organized way.

Comment: by AnaConda do you mean the jupyter notebook? I started python in anaconda jupyter notebook. but the downloaded files were in py format. As I want to edit the code, I switched to IDLE.

Comment: AnaConda is a package management software. Jupyter Notebook and IDLE are two tools used to edit and run python codes, namely IDEs. AnaConda can be used to install Jupyter Notebook or/and IDLE. You can view AnaConda as aptget or yum or brew for python, and it supports projects in C++ and other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps, and it worked for me to **install mayavi**.

```
git clone https://github.com/enthought/mayavi.git
cd mayavi
pip install PyQt5 vtk
python setup.py install
```

I took the reference from the official page https://pypi.org/project/mayavi/

Answer (score -1):

The main probem was VTK installation. I tried the procedure explained here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgvbhyDh8r0&t=222s

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is it possible to write the actions in text?